# sqlite3 COUNT in iOS (specifically ON the iPhone/iPad)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I know that the simulator and the actual iOS hardware are not EXACTLY the same, but I'm starting to pull my hair out over this one. I have this code:

```
sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
int themeCount;

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Theme"];
    const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

        if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            themeCount = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

With the simulator, it works perfectly fine. Once I push it to my devices, it fails. I've broken it down and came up with the return code where it fails:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

If I change that line to capture the code (ie. int x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(...)) it returns 0 with the simulator, 1 with the device. What am I doing wrong here?!?!

Also, for the record, the CREATE statement for the Theme table is:

```
@"CREATE TABLE Theme (ThemeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ThemeName TEXT, Available BIT);"
```

(My first thought is that it was case sensitive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not opening the database you think you are opening. The `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is the first statement that needs the schema to be present. I suspect your `databasePath` is incorrect.

You can be more specific with `sqlite3_open_v2` by omitting the `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` flag which is the default with `sqlite3_open` so you don't notice that a new database is being created by the open call. See [SQLite3 docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html). With the result of

```
sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL)
```

you will see that the database does not exist.

Comment: The database does exist, and it's the one I'm expecting to open. When I drop a breakpoint in at the beginning of the execution of the app (where it does some updating to the database, etc) it finds the database at a certain location (/var/mobile/Applications/{GUID}/Documents/{dbname}) the method in question (above) has the EXACT same path, plus, when I altered my code to look like yours (in your answer), that "passes" (ie. SQLITE_OK). It still gets inside, runs the prepare_v2 and skips over any rows (ie. same result). This is really frustrating!!!

Comment: OK, So, you were definitely correct (at least partially). Apparently, in the simulator, there is no difference between databasename.sqlite and DatabaseName.sqlite, but for the iPhone, they are very different. So, it was the same name, but it wasn't finding the ACTUAL file. A million Thanks for pointing me in the right direction and helping me solve this!